# Image in a PDF rendering with artifacts at various zooms in Adobe Reader or Kofax Power PDF, but normal in internet browsers

Tags: pdf, artifacts

Image in a PDF rendering with artifacts at various zooms in Adobe Reader or Kofax Power PDF, but normal in internet browsers. Focus on 125% zoom, Kofax Power PDF one.

I have same issue with PNG, JPEG, tiff images.

Examples below.  Why does it render differently, and how do I force consistency?

[100% zoom, Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJRpM.png)

[125% zoom, CHrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9QuB.png)

[100% zoom, Kofax Power PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu9NJ.png)

[125% zoom, Kofax Power PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywwK2.png)

I tried using different file formats, but it is consistently different.

Comment: First of all, you don't show us the source PDF. If we don't have that, how do you expect us to tell you what to do differently? That being said, though, the PDF specification does not mention how exactly to deal with bitmap images that aren't positioned bitmap pixel on display pixel, so there may be differences in the displayed data.

Answer (score 1):

As PNG pixel images neither have artifacts here are the 2 x 100% side by side where all we see is a miniscule shift in AntiAlias there are no JPEG halos or averaging here. The "problem" is simply which square should be which colour when vectors are sliced by a pixel boundary.

[image]

125%
2 different rendering engines will interpolate vectors slightly differently due to screen position and algorithms.
[image]

When you use JPEG then you see artefacts, here on the left is JPEG from PNG on the right.
[image]

JPEG outer colour aberrations (halos) are more noticeable when we reverse the background or it is translucent.

[image]

Comment: How do i produce a PDF that is displayed consistently? Or is this just something I have to deal with because everyone opens pdfs with various programs that use varied algorithms.
And why adobe is the one that's underperforming?